# HTML Email with Gmail - appending space underneath images

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

I've been trying to figure this out for a day and none of the tutorials seem to have the fix.  Does anyone know why Gmail Adds a margin?  It seems to append a span with two underline tags within a span which causes a 3 pixel margin underneath.

`<table>
<tr><td colspan="2" width="700" height="632" valign="top"><a href="" border="0" ><img src="test image here" width="700" height="632" border="0" alt="test" style="display: block;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" width="700" height="28" valign="top"><a href="mailto:" title="Email"><img src="test image" width="700" height="28" border="0" alt="Email" style="display: block;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Figured it out... Outlook is appending a CSS class

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=0076054aff3bc664&hl=en

Comment: just to note, I insert this email using outlook to test. "Insert as Text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... Outlook is appending a CSS class

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=0076054aff3bc664&hl=en